# Excel function or VBA script to combine ranges

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 2 columns each with a varying amount of rows. In this instance I want to merge (scalar multiple? multiple matrices?) the item in A1 with the range(B1:B50) and then repeat for each item in column A.

Ideally the two values would be separated by a comma. [Here's what I'd like to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ak1s.jpg).

What would be the best route to go? Can the matrix function work for combining text?

Comment: +1 I like this - you want to achieve a Cartesian product of the values in the columns. So easy in sql.

Comment: @whytheq Tell me more. I'm essentially prepping data from two database tables to insert into another table.

Comment: I've added an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Sub sample()

    Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowB As Long, row As Long

    lastRowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastRowB = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    row = 1
    For i = 1 To lastRowA
        For j = 1 To lastRowB
            Cells(row, 4) = Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(row, 5) = Cells(i, 1) & "," & Cells(j, 2)
            row = row + 1
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data from SQL then a `CROSS JOIN` gives you the Cartesian product of the two sets of data.

Then you could just concatenate together.

Using SQL-Server here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #x (columnX CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO #x
    values
    ('a'),
    ('b'),
    ('c');

CREATE TABLE #y (columnY CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO #y
    values
    ('d'),
    ('e'),
    ('f');


SELECT  #x.columnX,
    #y.columnY,
    #x.columnX + ', ' +  #y.columnY
FROM    #x
    CROSS JOIN #y
```